# Will downloading a page builder plugin delete my existing data?

Tags: plugins, advanced-custom-fields

I had a website developer build my website. Now I want to add content myself. Will WPBakery Page Builder be compatible? If I activate the plugin will all my existing data be erased?

Answer (score 0):

No it won't.  it will still be there and WPbakery will format it into one of it's text boxes if you choose that editor on a page/post edit screen.  It's always a good idea to back your site / db up if you are concerned about it though!